# Z-index of a JavaScript generated facebook plugin

Tags: html, facebook, plugins, z-index, blogger

I added a facebook like plugin to my posts, but if i press the "send" button, the opening "inner-window" is under the widget I placed to the right side of my blog. How can I place the plugin at the top?

My blog: http://fresh-social-media-news.blogspot.com/2011/06/second-post.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the overflow:hidden attribute off of #main-wrapper (line #385)